# Is it possible to read from MYSQL-database to get valid IP-Adresses for Pingtable

Tags: linux, iptables, mysql, firewall

is it possible that `iptables` reads the IP-Adresses it should packages from from a MYSQL-database?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what exactly you're asking.  But a shell script could easily take data from MySQL database and pass it to `iptables`.

Comment: It should get a list from my MYSQL-database, which contains the IP-Addresses that are allowed to receive packages from outside the network. If the IP-Address stands on the list, the package should be delivered, else not.

Comment: No.  iptables does not have that functionality natively.  Scripting required.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "scripting"?

Comment: Write a script that reads the data from database.  From there issue the relevant iptables commands combined with the data from the database to setup the firewall filter list.